# Get a trained net and the training session properties?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, version-11.1

In version 11.1 there is an additional signature for NetTrain:

[image]

But this only returns the property, how can I get the net and the list of properties I want?

Minimal example code:

```
data = {1 -> 2.2, 2 -> 3.8, 3 -> 6.4, 4 -> 9.1};
layer = LinearLayer[];
net = NetTrain[layer, data, 
  MeanAbsoluteLossLayer[], {"RoundLossList"}, Method -> "SGD"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, `"TrainedNet"` returns the trained net, so I think this does what you want:

```
{net, roundLossList} = 
 NetTrain[layer, data, 
  MeanAbsoluteLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "RoundLossList"}, 
  Method -> "SGD"]
```